# Выборка из базы в нужном порядке строго по запросу

Tags: mysqli

Мой запрос для выборки пользователей с таблицы.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id IN (1,8,7,4)
```

В результате получаю `1,4,7,8` а хочу получить результат в таком порядке как и сам запрос `1,8,7,4` как написать правильно запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id IN (1,8,7,4) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1,8,7,4)
```